# This is not an IQ test question

Tags: visual

This is not from any IQ test. You should get the answer right away, I think.

What replaces the question mark? There are three choices. Please explain your answer.

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The answer is

> The P!!

Because

> These are all little symbols that appear in the background of the main site!
>
>  [image]
>
> You could also argue the answer is actually none, because the question mark also is one of the symbols as you can see above ;)

Comment: your last comment is very astute. I was thinking about having the question mark the same "color"  as the others too.

Comment: @DrD Id say same colour would have been too much of a giveaway, but it’d been interesting how long it would have taken to click that the question mark is actually one of the symbols, if say the 3 symbols all were wrong. I only noticed the question mark coming back to this about an hour ago, but I really like that bonus :P

Comment: Lol this one is perhaps not ideal for mobile

Comment: @ConnorMcCormick definitely not unfortunately :)

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I was way off! I thought the answer was:

> [image]

Because:

> It appears alongside the other answer choices and you wrote "You should get the **answer** right away." Pretty easy to get the "answer" when it's written right there!

Answer (score 0):

> The answer is the P

Because:

> Not perfect reasoning, but the 1st and 3rd image of each row seem to be most similar. There are some rotational and sizing differences, and for the line with the circles it looks like a bit of the symbol was chopped off. In the final row, if you chopped off the loopy bit of the P and rotated it, you'd get the first symbol from that row. That same operation doesn't seem possible with the other 2 options.

Though I treated it like an IQ test question despite the question's description.

Comment: I thought this as well. In absence of the insight of the background symbols, I figured each row was the silhouette of the same 3-d object, being viewed at different distances and angles. Row 1 is a pair of rods/prisms joined at a right angle. Row 2 is a cube. Row 3 I couldn't figure out, but it seemed plausible enough. Row 4, while you could technically have a 3-d shape that rotates from a line/rectangle into any of those shapes, the P did seem the most intuitive match.

Comment: Hello @Qami. I designed it this way knowing that while you are reading the question, you are literally looking at the answer (in the background)!